# Accessing information in a JSON nested in object

Tags: json

I'm trying to access the roomName, but so far I am unable. I don't get how to get past the barriar of the info.[long ID with dashes].roomName.

At most I can get back the object of the long id or undefined.

I have tried info[0].roomName. Trying to get the first object in the info and then go on from there.  The long id number is also in list.id,  I don't know if that can help.

I would have set the info as an array like list is, but this is not my JSON, only one that I am working with.

```
    {  
       "list":[ IGNORE, can access code here ],
       "info":{  
          "e5eb1ccf-bd45-4d01-8e2a":{  
             "id":"e5eb1ccf-bd45-4d01-8e2a",
             "name":"Lucy",
             "roomName":"Arts" <<I need to get to this.
         }
    }
 }
```

I hope this makes sense, first post and this is just a boiled down version of what I have.  Putting in the id number in the info.e5eb1ccf-bd45-4d01-8e2a.roomName breaks after the first -

Answer (score 1):

Once you've parsed the JSON (assuming you even have JSON*) and you have an object, you'd use brackets notation:

```
var room = theObject.info["e5eb1ccf-bd45-4d01-8e2a"].roomName;
console.log(room); // Arts
```

---

* Remember, JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. [(More here.)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247) If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON.